# Log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, java-native-interface, log4cplus

I am working on a Swing app that uses native code. Each time I run my project, I get the error message:

> log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger.
>
> log4cplus:ERROR Please initialize the log4cplus system properly.

Since logging for log4cplus is not properly configured, when ever I get an error somewhere in native code, it's not logged.

I've searched the internet for a solution to this problem all to no avail.

The solution I found said to uninstall `AutoDesk 360`, but I don't have this installed.

I searched for a `.jar` file for `log4cplus` but found a zip instead with files that am not sure how to add to my project.

This can be found here on Github.

[log4cplus](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus)

If I right-click on my project and go to find and type `log4cplus`, nothing with that name exists in my project. The same search for `log4j` brings up the `log4j.properties` file and a whole list of other usages

Comment: @wilx can you provide a solution to this? I already downloaded the log4cplus project but am not sure how to add this to a java project.